# Trouble finding error in my proof for Baby Rudin exercise 4.1

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I was working on exercise 4.1 of Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Rudin which states

> Suppose $f$ is a real function defined on $\mathbb{R}^1$ which satisfies
>   $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}[f(x+h)-f(x-h)]=0$$
>   for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^1$. Does this imply that $f$ is continuous?

I now know that the answer is in fact "no" and understand the given proof for why. However I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out where I went wrong in my proof that the statement does imply that $f$ is continuous:

> Let  $$g(h)=f(p+h)-f(p-h)$$ By the definition of a limit we know that
>   for each $p\in \mathbb{R}$ for all $\epsilon_0>0$ there exists a
>   $\delta_0>0$ such that $$d_Y(g(h),0)<\epsilon_0$$ for all $h$ where
>   $$0<d_X(h,0)<\delta_0$$ We wish to show that for each $p\in\mathbb{R}$
>   for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that
>   $$d_Y(f(x),f(p))<\epsilon$$  for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ for which
>   $$0<d_X(x,p)<\delta$$ Let us consider  \begin{align}  
>   d_Y(g(h),0)&=|f(p+h)-f(p-h)|\\
>               &=|f(p+h)+f(p)-f(p)-f(p-h)|\\
>              &\leq |f(p+h)-f(p)|+|f(p-h)-f(p)|\\
>               &=d_Y(f(p+h),f(p))+d_Y(f(p-h),f(p))\\
>               &\textrm{If }d_Y(f(p+h),f(p))\geq d_Y(f(p-h),f(p))\textrm{ then}\\
>               &\leq2d_Y(f(p+h),f(p))\leq \epsilon_0\\
>               &\textrm{Else}\\
>               &\leq2d_Y(f(p-h),f(p))\leq\epsilon_0\\ \end{align} We find this relation to be true for all $h$ such that $$0<|h|<\delta_0$$ We can
>   see that this corresponds to the following statement:
>
> For each $p\in\mathbb{R}$ for all $\epsilon_0>0$
>   $$2d_Y(f(x),f(p))\leq \epsilon_0 $$ is true for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ for
>   which $$0<d_X(x,p)<\delta_0$$ This is the statement that $f$ is
>   continuous at all point $p\in\mathbb{R}$.

I was wondering if someone could help we locate where I went awry

Comment: Do you know what the counter example is? IE a function that satisfies the conditions and isn't continuous. If so, read your proof using that function as an example, and see where it breaks down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you find a counterexample to the question? What function satisfies the conditions but isn't continuous?

> $f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \forall x \neq 0 \\ 1 & x = 0 \end{cases}  $

---

If you consider the counterexample while reading your proof, you will find that this step is suspect at the point of discontinuity ($ p = 0$ in my example).

> Let us consider  \begin{align}  
>   d_Y(g(h),0)&=|f(p+h)-f(p-h)|\\
>               &=|f(p+h)+f(p)-f(p)-f(p-h)|\\
>              &\leq |f(p+h)-f(p)|+|f(p-h)-f(p)|\\
>               &=d_Y(f(p+h),f(p))+d_Y(f(p-h),f(p))\\
>               &\textrm{If }d_Y(f(p+h),f(p))\geq d_Y(f(p-h),f(p))\textrm{ then}\\
>               &\leq2d_Y(f(p+h),f(p))\leq \epsilon_0\\
>               &\textrm{Else}\\
>               &\leq2d_Y(f(p-h),f(p))\leq\epsilon_0\\ \end{align}

(Lots of abuse of $\epsilon$ notation used here. You may treat them as mostly distinct.)

You have no information about $|f(p+h)-f(p)|$, and couldn't draw that conclusion (in the last 2 lines).
You are wanting to show (in the previous line of your proof), that this value is $ \leq \epsilon$.
In fact, referring to my example, we had $|f(0+h) - f(0)| = 1$, and cannot bound it by $\epsilon$.
You ended up assuming that it was $ \leq \epsilon$ (in the last 2 lines) in order to prove that it was $ \leq \epsilon$.

---

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I think I see where I went wrong. Just a question though, what did you mean by "Lots of abuse of $\epsilon$ notation used here?" I'm not too familiar with what that means.

Comment: As in, by right, I should be using $ \epsilon_0, \epsilon_1, \ldots $ to distinguish them. But I'm too lazy to do so / keep track of them, so I'm not doing that indexing.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you for the clarification!